# Strongly typed database vb.net delete all records

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ms-access-2007, strongly-typed-dataset

```
   Dim ddrc As Int16 = (Me.Temp_QuotesDataGridView.RowCount - 1)
    With (Me.Temp_QuotesDataGridView)
        For Xxx = ddrc To 0 Step -1
            .Rows.Remove(.Rows(Xxx))
        Next
    End With
    Me.Validate()
    Me.Temp_QuotesBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.Temp_QuotesTableAdapter.Update(Me.M_B_DATABASEDataSet)
```

Whats wrong with that code that it doesn't really delete from the database
it shows the records are gone from the datagridview but when I open the database all the records are still.
I am using vb.net strongly typed access database.

Comment: Try doing a `Me.Temp_QuotesDataGridView.EndEdit()` immediately before the `Me.Temp_QuotesBindingSource.EndEdit()` and see if that helps.

Comment: Me.Temp_QuotesDataGridView.EndEdit()    didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following code and it worked for me:

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Const MyTableName = "dgvTest"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection( _
                "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=C:\Users\Public\mdbTest.mdb;")
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & MyTableName & "]", con)
        Dim cb = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        cb.QuotePrefix = "["
        cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"
        dt = New DataTable()
        Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = dt
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.BindingSource1
        da.Fill(dt)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim i As Long
        With Me.DataGridView1
            Dim NumDataRows As Long = .RowCount - IIf(.AllowUserToAddRows, 1, 0)
            For i = NumDataRows - 1 To 0 Step -1
                .Rows.Remove(.Rows(i))
            Next
        End With
        da.Update(dt)
        MessageBox.Show("The table has been emptied.")
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```